# FAB over tab bar in Ionic and events

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I need to be able to place a FAB over a tab bar in Ionic. I've done this successfully.

[image]

This is done in my Home component (`home.html` and `home.ts`). The tab bar declaration is:

```
<ion-tabs color="tabbar">
  <ion-tab [root]="dashboard" tabIcon="home" tabTitle="Home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="activity" tabIcon="trending-up" tabTitle="Activity">   
</ion-tab>
  <ion-fab center bottom>
    <button ion-fab large (click)="showTransferOptions($event)">Transfer</button>
  </ion-fab>
  <ion-tab [root]="transfer" tabIcon="deliberately_invalid" tabTitle="">     
</ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="contacts" tabIcon="contacts" tabTitle="Contacts"> 
</ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="settings" tabIcon="cog" tabTitle="Settings"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

My `home.ts` as the function declared:

```
showTransferOptions(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: co.showTransferOptions is not a function
```

I am a bit new to Ionic so I'm not quite sure why this isn't binding. I thought that the 'Home' component had a controller behind it that would mkae bindings like this possible?

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: Tried your same code that is working fine without issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks for checking. And indeed this seems to be an Ionic issue with hot reloading: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1239

Comment: Hi Ben ,I also need to be able to place a FAB over a tab bar in Ionic. Can you please share your HTML/CSS code with me.

Answer (score 0):

When navigating from root pages of the tabs.ts dont use `NavController` use `App` from `ionic-angular` like this `this.appCtrl.getRootNav().push('Pagetogoto');` that will completely remove the `tabs.html` and hide that `Fab`